# Values in scripts

Tags: newmips

I have an app with an entity `Order` with a field `Status`. The values of the `Status` is "related to" an entity `Status` in the admin module which contains one field with values : Shipped, Resolved, Cancelled, On hold, Disputed, In Process.

Is it possible to define these values in the nps script ?

Answer (score 0):

No. It's not if you use a field "related to". You must fill in form of entity status to provide values you want.

If you want your drop down list to rely on values that you write in your script, you must use "enum" type.

```
add field Status with type enum and values Shipped, Resolved, Cancelled, On hold, Disputed, In Process
```

But this way, you won't benefit from status component features.

Comment: When will it possible to have a `add field (.*) value (.*)` in nps scripts ?